# print in a loop Python Windows

Tags: python, django, shell

I noticed something strange when using the Django shell on Windows. I tested different calls with a simple script which is :

```
for it in range(5): 
    print(it)
```

When typing this script in a Python environment or a `manage.py shell` one, it works fine. But when I put this code in a file and execute it with `python manage.py shell < myFile.py` there's nothing which is displayed when I'm printing in loops, the output is "..." instead.

I overpassed this restriction by executing it in the build-in console from Eclipse but I'm pretty curious of the reasons why the output isn't well displayed when calling the script from an output file.

Does anyone knows what happened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way:

```
echo 'execfile("myFile.py")' | python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 2):

Both worked fine

In addition, for those who are using Python 3+, execfile doesn't work anymore, replace

```
echo 'execfile("myFile.py")' | python manage.py shell
```

with

```
echo exec(open('MyFile.py').read()) | python manage.py shell
```

Thanks for both of you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

`echo "for i in range(5): print i" | python manage.py shell`

Comment: I think the question is about running external scripts using django shell.